# Importing from old table into new table with different structure

Tags: mysql, import

My old table had around 600 columns. Let's call this table `old_table`.

My new table has 603 columns. Let's call this table `new_table`.

Now to import the data from `old_table` into `new_table`, I tried following the below approach:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename' AND TABLE_NAME = 'old_table'");

$cols = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{   
   $cols[] = $r['COLUMN_NAME'];     
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO new_table ";
$sql .= "SELECT ";
$sql .= implode(", ", $cols);
$sql .= " FROM old_table";

mysql_query($sql) or die("Something went wrong: ".mysql_error());
```

But this is resulting into **`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`** because the query is also taking into account the 3 new columns of `new_table`.

Is there a way I can make it skip the additional columns in the `new_table` and insert all data from `old_table`?

Comment: I think you forgot to put elements in array like `$i = 0; ... $cols[$i] = ...; $i += 1;`

Comment: I don't see that as a necessary step, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can either provide default values for the new columns and add those to your insert statement, or you can name the columns you want to insert into.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO new_table ";
$sql .= "SELECT ";
$sql .= implode(", ", $cols);
$sql .= ", value_for_new_column_1";
$sql .= ", value_for_new_column_2";
$sql .= ", value_for_new_column_3";
$sql .= " FROM old_table";
```

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO new_table ";
$sql .= "(" . implode(", ", $cols) . ")";
$sql .= "SELECT ";
$sql .= implode(", ", $cols);
$sql .= " FROM old_table";
```

Comment: Unbelievable! How on earth did I miss such a simple thing. Too bad I can't upvote because of the reputation restriction. Anyways, will accept as answer in a bit as it isn't allowing me to do so at the moment.

Comment: The first approach isn't desirable as that would be too much work for a table with 600 columns

Comment: Thanks! And actually, you'd only need to provide defaults for the _new_ columns, not for all of them. See my first example.